# How do I solve: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "s%"?

Tags: java, android

I'm new to android studio and I've been recently working on an app that allows you to make orders and in order to order something you add things to a cart and then can later check the details from your account page. When the cart is clicked, the app crashed and this shows up:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.sakaaz.sakaaz, PID: 16627
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sakaaz.sakaaz/edmt.dev.androidsakaaz.Cart}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "s%"
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
               Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "s%"
                  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:521)
                  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:556)
                  at edmt.dev.androidsakaaz.Cart.loadListMakeup(Cart.java:68)
                  at edmt.dev.androidsakaaz.Cart.onCreate(Cart.java:56)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

My database looks like:

```js
    public class Database extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "sakaazDB.db";
private static final int DB_VER=1;


public Database(Context context) {
    super( context, DATABASE_NAME, null , DB_VER );
}

public List<Order> getCarts()
{
    SQLiteDatabase db=getReadableDatabase();
    SQLiteQueryBuilder qb= new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

    String[] sqlSelect={"ProductName", "ProductId", "Quantity", "Price", "Discount"};
    String sqlTable="OrderDetail";

    qb.setTables( sqlTable );
    Cursor c = qb.query(db,sqlSelect,null,null,null,null,null);

    final List<Order> result = new ArrayList<>();
    if (c.moveToFirst())
    {
        do{
            result.add( new Order( c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("ProductId")),
                    c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("ProductName")),
                    c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Quantity")),
                    c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Price")),
                    c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Discount"))
                    ));
        }while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    return result;
}

public void addToCart (Order order)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    String query = String.format("INSERT INTO OrderDetail(ProductId, ProductName, Quantity, Price, Discount) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s');",
            order.getProductId(),
            order.getProductName(),
            order.getQuantity(),
            order.getPrice(),
            order.getDiscount());

    db.execSQL(query);
}


public void cleanCart()
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    String query = "DELETE FROM OrderDetail";
    db.execSQL(query);
}
}
```

While the cart looks like:

```js
public class Cart extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference request;

    TextView txtTotalPrice;
    FButton btnPlace;

    List<Order> cart = new ArrayList<>();

    CartAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.activity_cart );

        //Firebase
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        request = database.getReference("Requests");

        //Init
        recyclerView= (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.listCart);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize (true);
        layoutManager= new LinearLayoutManager( this );
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager( layoutManager );

        txtTotalPrice = (TextView)findViewById( R.id.total);
        btnPlace = (FButton)findViewById( R.id.btnPlaceOrder);

        loadListMakeup();

    }

    private void loadListMakeup() {
        cart = new Database(this).getCarts();
        adapter = new CartAdapter( cart,this );
        recyclerView.setAdapter( adapter );

        //Calculate total price
        int total=0;
        for (Order order:cart)
            total+=(Integer.parseInt( order.getPrice()))*(Integer.parseInt( order.getQuantity()));
        Locale locale = new Locale( "en","US");
        NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);

        txtTotalPrice.setText(fmt.format( total));
    }
}
```

I'm new to android studio and this is my first time working with it and I'm very lost since I'm doing this for a highschool IT project so please help!

Comment: Not a JavaScript question

Comment: Can you share database helper class code ?

Answer (score 0):

in your addToCart method..

```
SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("ProductId", order.getProductId());
//..your all data
database.insert("OrderDetail", null, values);
database.close();
```

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

According to LogCat, Issue is in your formatting in this line.

```
total+=(Integer.parseInt( order.getPrice()))*(Integer.parseInt( order.getQuantity()));
```

First of all remove those spaces after calling `Integer.parseInt()`

Replace your `setText()` method with this

```
txtTotalPrice.setText(String.valueOf(total));
```

your problem is in database you have called c.getString() for integer value that's why you got FormatException.

Replace it with this:

```
c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Price")),
```

And check any other place where you might have copy pasted trying to save five seconds of your life.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple errors in your code

1.Replace your

```
 getReadableDatabase();
```

with

```
 getWritableDatabase();
```

and then,

2.Check the values of following methods wether it returns exact int value otherwise NumberformatException will trigger.

```
 order.getPrice()//may be not an int
 order.getQuantity()//may be not an int
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I did this and it still didn't work.